# How to #ifdef the __builtin_prefetch function

Tags: c, conditional-compilation

How do I keep `__builtin_prefetch()` in my code, but make compilers that do not have it compile successfully? (Just doing nothing where it is found).

Comment: "keep it"? people tend to create a wrapper.

Comment: `_mm_prefetch` is slightly more portable by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__builtin_prefetch()` is recognised by the compiler (gcc) not the preprocessor, so you won't be able to detect it using the C preprocessor.

Since an identifier with two leading underscores is reserved for use by the implementation (so any code you use which defines such an identifier has undefined behaviour) I'd do it the other way around.

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#define do_prefetch(x) __builtin_prefetch(x)
#else
#define do_prefetch(x)
#endif
```

and then use

```
do_prefetch(whatever);
```

where needed.

That way there is no code emitted unless it is actually needed.

Since `__builtin_prefetch()` accepts a variable number of arguments, you might want to adapt the above to use variadic macros (C99 and later) - if you use it with different numbers of arguments in different places in your code.

Answer (score 0):

It is not exactly the best solution, but it will disable `__builtin_prefetch()` on all other compilers other than GCC.

```
#ifndef __GNUC__
#   define __builtin_prefetch(x)
#endif
```